# create tree structure in ag grid with pagination filter and sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, grid, treeview

I am trying to create **tree structure in ag-grid with pagination filter and sort**. Child row of the tree should take full width of that row and should not be specific to the columns.

Need **json format** for the parent child view in ag-grid

if ag-grid or ng-grid cannot implement this, plz suggest a new one in angular js

Comment: As far as I could find there is no tree structure support - but i found the [grid grouping](http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-grouping/index.php) options, which renders a tree like structure. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: @michael I tried grid grouping but its not working with server side sorting as given [here](http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-pagination/index.php) . I need to re edit the json format for sorting the data.